# Transform array of int into 7bytes variable

Tags: c++, c

I have an array of int: int temp[56], each of the elements equal to '1' or '0'. Is it real to transform this array of int into one 7bytes variable using code like this??

```
int temp[56]={...};
int a=0;
int b=0;

for (int i=0; i<56; i++)
{
b=temp[i];
a|=(b<<i);
```

Comment: sizeof(int) is 2 or 4 bytes.  Where is your 7bytes variable?

Comment: @abhineetprasad: Technically, `int` can be anything from 1 to infinite bytes, but it has to have at least 16 **bits**. (So at least 2 octets, even if it's one byte). But yeah, 7 bytes is rather unlikely. The only common type which is 7 bytes is `char[7]`.

Comment: @MSalters : Thanks,didnt know that. I knew that sizeof(int) was compiler dependent but didnt realize that compiler could very well set the sizeof(int) at 7 bytes if it so wanted to, but it makes sense.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 56 `int`s that will always only have the value of either `0` or `1`, then you really have 56 `bool`s in extra-large packages.  You can fix that by:

1) Use an array of bools

```
bool arr[56];
```

2) Use `std::vector<bool>`

```
std::vector<bool> arr;
```

3) Use `std::bitset<SIZE>`

```
std::bitset<56> arr;
```

4) If you absolutely must (for some reason), package them in an integer (assuming a 32-bit integer):

```
unsigned int arr[2]; // 2*32 = 64, so we have enough space for all 56 flags
// to set the i'th bit
arr[i / 32] |= 1U << (i % 32);
// or to clear the i'th bit
arr[i / 32] &= ~(1U << (i % 32));
```

One of the first 3 options should be preferred.

Comment: Much cleaner: `std::bitset<56>`.

Comment: @MSalters  I knew I'd forget one ... I'll add that.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you do come up with some 64bit variable, the shift operator itself is not likely to work beyond 31, and even if it does - some ISAs (x86 for e.g.) might mask it - http://choorucode.com/2004/12/20/c-shift-operator-mayhem/

Comment: @Leeor:  IA-64 doesn't have that same restriction, but in order for the compiler to recognize it, you have to make sure it knows you want to shift a 64-bit variable (e.g. `1LL << 33` will work since the width of the left operand is of sufficient size).

Comment: @Leeor: No, they don't. In particular, what Zac Howland says about IA-64 applies everywhere. Your compiler **must** make it work. On an ancient Z80 that would be painful, with only 8 bit shifts, but it still would be up to the compiler to generate the two dozen instructions needed. And if a compiler implements `long long` as 128 bits, it must even offer a 127 bit shift.

Comment: Right, 1LL would do the trick, but it's easy to slip and use `1 << ..` tricks without checking the shift size

Comment: The `1` in `...  1 << ...` should be `unsigned` (`1u`) rather than signed (`1`) to prevent UB.  If larger integer types are desired, then `1ul` or `1ull` could be used.

Comment: @chux:  True.  Corrected for completeness.

Comment: @Leeor The C Shift Operator Mayhem post is now at: http://codeyarns.com/2004/12/20/c-shift-operator-mayhem/

Answer (score 0):

C solution: Close to OP's suggestion, but use `int64_t` to insure bit shift works and is sufficiently large for the result.  Could use `long long` instead.

```
int temp[56]={...};  // temp filled with 0 or 1.
int64_t a=0;

for (int i=0; i<56; i++) {
  a |= ((int64_t) temp[i]) << i;
}
```